# How set Edition/Size for database created by Code First

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure Sql Databases and Entity Framework Code First 6.1. The whole solution is deployed to Azure Web Site. I have a custom inheritor of DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer configured for my DbContext.

In future I plan to switch to EF Migrations but it's more convenient at the moment to not worry about migrations in the early state of the project. Though the problem is that everytime database is recreated with **1GB** size. I want it to be **100mb** by default for the pricing reason. How can I achieve that using my setup?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617969/how-to-programatically-create-sql-azure-database-of-type-basic-standard-edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you cannot change the behavior of the default initializer. But there are two possible options:

1. write custom database initializer.
2. use a standard initializer and execute custom sql after db is created:

   `ALTER DATABASE [dbname] MODIFY (MAXSIZE = 100 Mb)`

Comment: This is what I get {"ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction."}

Comment: I have this same problem. Solution is add SQL statement in Intial database after create model.