# How to create a sql database in Basic edition programmatically? in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

The syntax for this is explained here:

[How to programatically create Sql Azure database of type Basic/Standard edition through Enity Framework code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617969/how-to-programatically-create-sql-azure-database-of-type-basic-standard-edition)

However, my code is implemented like this:

```
 public static bool CreateDatabaseIfNotExists(string connectionString, string databaseName)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    string.Format("SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=\'{0:S}\'", databaseName),
                    conn);

                cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;

                if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
                        string.Format("CREATE DATABASE [{0:S}];", databaseName),
                        conn);
                    cmd2.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;

                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

Where exactly should I put the basic string, as I am not sure where to place it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specify the edition after the name of the DB:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(string.Format("CREATE DATABASE [{0:S}] (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'basic');", databaseName), conn);
```

The documentation for the syntax can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx)